# Fixing my Perms Function for lists with the same object

Tags: haskell

Hey guys my assigment for my perms haskell task got declined and i may could need some help with my code

```
perms :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms lst = [x:xs | x <- lst, xs <- (perms (filter(\xs -> xs /= x) lst))]
```

. This code generates the perm of a list like [1,2] -> [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

My problem is that i failed the test for the input [1,1] which should be [[1,1],[1,1]] but my function gets us [[1],[1]] because i did declare in my list comprehension that same objects don't get into the same list.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out elements *without* `filter` and even without the `Eq` type constraint.

You can make a function `pick` that for a list picks an item and returns the list of remaining elements, like:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick [] = []
pick (x : xs) = (x, xs) : …
```

where I leave the `…` part as an exercise. Hint: you will need to prepend `x` to each (sub)list of the recursive call.

With this `pick` function, we can make permutations with:

```
perm :: [a] -> [[a]]
perm [] = [[]]
perm xs = [ x : zs | (x, ys) <- pick xs, zs <- perms ys ]
```

We thus pick an item from the list, and then we create permutations by pretending that element to all permutations of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part with identical elements can be avoided by getting permutations of a list of `Int` from `[0..(len xs - 1)]`.  This creates a list of all *orders* which can be mapped to the given list as indices.  The advantage here is that a list of `Int` as indices can be easily manipulated with `delete`.  One can put one of each of the indices in the first position and `cons` that with all the permutations of the remaining indices.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Data.List (delete)

type Order = [Int]

allOrders :: [Int] -> [Order]
allOrders [] = [[]]
allOrders xs = [y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- allOrders (delete y xs)]

listToOrders :: [a] -> [Order] -> [[a]]
listToOrders xs orders = [map (xs !!) order | order <- orders]

perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms xs = listToOrders xs (allOrders [0..(length xs - 1)])

npr :: Int -> Int
npr 0 = 1
npr 1 = 1
npr x = x * npr (x-1) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

prop_given0 :: Property
prop_given0 = property (perms [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],
                                          [2,1,3],[2,3,1],
                                          [3,1,2],[3,2,1]])
prop_given1 :: Property
prop_given1 = property (perms [1,1] == [[1,1],[1,1]])

prop_numberOfPermutations :: Eq a => [a] -> Property
prop_numberOfPermutations xs =
  property (length (perms xs) == npr (length xs)) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

{-- 
*Main> quickCheck prop_given0
+++ OK, passed 1 test.
*Main> quickCheck prop_given1
+++ OK, passed 1 test.
*Main> quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSize = 10 } prop_numberOfPermutations 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
--}
```